# how to get android EditText column

Tags: java, android

I have one EditText, and I want to get the current column position.

I am using SDK 1.5

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this out, but I'm guessing that either getSelectionStart() or getSelectionEnd() will return the position of the cursor based on the api docs.

Comment: that is true, but can I get for each individual line? It seems that this one gives for the whole EditText